# deserializing a nested list in xml

Tags: c#, xml, silverlight, deserialization, xml-deserialization

I am c# silverlight beginner i am under a situation that i have thios xml code:

```
        string xmlstring = @"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?> 
                           <par>  
                           <name>amount</name>
                           <label>Amount</label>
                           <unit>Hundred</unit >
                           <comp>
                           <type>Combo</type>
                           <attributes>
                           <type>Integer</type>
                           <displayed>4</displayed>
                           <selected>0</selected>
                           <item>5</item>       
                           </attributes>
                           </comp>
                           </par>";
```

** Now what is the problem ?**
In the last line when i try to debug "item" which is asssigned several value like `5` on line Debug.WriteLine(attrib.item);i just see only `"5"` on debugging it dont show other values. I guess i need to implement a list for it. But how to do it here that i don't know. Could some one please help me so that i will be able to have all the assigned values to `item` in this c# code because after this step i havce to create a GUI of it. Woudl be a big help.

Note: I cannot use ArrayList because silverligth dont support it any other lastertnative please ?

Comment: There is something like `[XmlArray]` and `[XmlArrayItem]` which you should check and try.

Comment: @rosko What if i wanted to use list insted of arrays ? How willi do then ?

Comment: Your point? This is just a syntax... does the following example in answer below is not working for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you need:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "parameter")]
public class Parameter
{
    [XmlElement("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("label")]
    public string Label { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("unit")]
    public string Unit { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("component")]
    public Component Component { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "component")]
public class Component {
    [XmlElement("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("attributes")]
    public Attributes Attributes { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "attributes")]
public class Attributes
{
    [XmlElement("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("displayed")]
    public string Displayed { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("selected")]
    public string Selected { get; set; }
    [XmlArray("items")]
    [XmlArrayItem("item", typeof(string))]
    public List<string> Items { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string xmlstring = @"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?> 
                       <parameter>  
                       <name>max_amount</name>
                       <label>Max Amount</label>
                       <unit>Millions</unit>
                       <component>
                       <type>Combo</type>
                       <attributes>
                       <type>Integer</type>
                       <displayed>4</displayed>
                       <selected>0</selected>
                       <items>
                       <item>5</item>
                       <item>10</item>
                       <item>20</item>
                       <item>50</item>
                       </items>
                       </attributes>
                       </component >
                       </parameter>";


        XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Parameter));
        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xmlstring));

        Parameter parameter = (Parameter)deserializer.Deserialize(reader);

        Console.WriteLine("Type: {0}", parameter.Component.Attributes.Type);
        Console.WriteLine("Displayed: {0}", parameter.Component.Attributes.Displayed);
        Console.WriteLine("Selected: {0}", parameter.Component.Attributes.Selected);

        Console.WriteLine("Items: ");

        foreach (var item in parameter.Component.Attributes.Items)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\t{0}", item);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Note small change in xmlstring, now every `<item></item>` is inside container:

```
<items>
    <item>5</item>
    <item>10</item>
    <item>20</item>
    <item>50</item>
</items>
```

Comment: Thanks for the link.. But is it possible to do it using List insted of arrays ?

Comment: Your point...? It's just annotation for serializing and deserializing. You can serialize or deserialize Lists with it just fine.

Comment: it gives exception when i tried to do so. Could you please edit my code corresponding to the link taht you suggested ? Thanks a lot, would be a big help.

Comment: I done this in attribute.cs " [XmlArrayItem("item", typeof(attributes))]" ad this in component.cs "        [XmlArray("attributes")]   
        public List<attributes> attribut { get; set; } "

Comment: Error 1 The type or namespace name 'ArrayList' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly refernce on doing: "  [XmlArrayItem("item", typeof(attributes))]
        public ArrayList item { get; set; }" I am using silverlight-5 and i have included " System.Collections" even then it persists.

Comment: silverlight dont support "ArrayList" could you please explain it using "List" ?

Comment: where are displayed and selected in this xml ?

Comment: and why it is invalid ? could you please explain a bit more ?

Comment: Answer updated again. It's invalid because you can't really store attributes of type displayed, selected and item in one `List` - you can but this wouldn't be a good solution.

Comment: But i am obliged to do it and "even my previos xml didnt contained "items".

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52006/discussion-between-rosko-and-user234839)

Comment: And this line gives error :      foreach (var item in parameter.Component.Attributes.Items) This "Items is not recognozed"